# Cannot start cron on php-fpm docker

Tags: php, docker, cron

I am trying to start cron service on php-fpm docker. This is the sample code I am using :

```
......
RUN apt update
RUN apt install -y ..... cron
```

I tried to start the cron in the following ways :

`CMD .... && cron -f`

and ...

`RUN cron -f`

but it either fails in building or just don't start cron service.

I also tried with :

`cron`
and
`service cron start`

but with no success.

Comment: You typically need to run it in a separate container, as the main container `CMD`.  The linked question has several examples and alternate paths.

Comment: The program name is `crond`

Comment: I've read a lot threads before asking this question. The issue is that I see the step executing properly :
```Step 20/26 : RUN service cron start```
but then when I check with "service cron status" I see "failed". When I type "service cron start" in the container it works, but I can't do it each time I rebuild.